# Liferay 6: Unable to redirect to JSP from MVCPortlet

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

Depending upon a condition I want to redirect to a JSP Page from my MVCPortlet class, after setting `action-url-redirect` to true in `liferay-portlet.xml`, I tried with action

```
Response.sendRedirect()
```

and I got this error in the server console:

> Set render parameter has already been called

Then I tried using:

```
include("/html/satportlet/view2.jsp", request, response);
```

No exception is thrown but still nothing is happening in this case, and I don't know why.

Another question, am I right in assuming that in Liferay the concept of include and sendRedirect is same as that in JSP and Servlets?

I am using Liferay 6.

Answer (score 2):

No need for a redirect, add the following the end of your action method:

`response.setRenderParameter("jspPage", "/url/to/your/jsp");`

This will cause rendering of the page `"/url/to/your/jsp"` as a response to the action.

In fact, the only time I need to override `doView` is when I want custom processing before the entry-point view jsp is shown (to avoid writing code in the jsp itself, since Liferay has only a `jsp-page`/`view-template` as an init parameter and not a controller action).

Answer (score 0):

The portlet API differentiates between the action phase and the render phase: In the action phase (e.g. when you have an ActionRequest/ActionResponse available) you are not supposed to think about HTML output.

During render you decide what to show - so you'll just remember an attribute or render parameter during action handling. When rendering you'll redirect to/include the target JSP.

Comment: Thanks Olaf Kock , but waht i read is that , when using MVCPortlet there is no need of overriding the doView Method , as this is one of the advantage of using MVCPortlet , please let me know if i am wrong . Thanks in advance .